# Why is "content" buggy in webkit browsers?

Tags: css, webkit

I wanted to replace text on hover with css and though it didn't work, Google chrome ignored the entire `:hover` pseudo-class, while Mozilla firefox safely ignored `content` and continued to run the rest of the events

Html:

```
<li id="menuDebating"><a href="xc_debating.htm">Debating</a></li>​
```

Css:

```
#menuDebating a:hover{
content: "Public Speaking" !important;
color:red;
}​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FSyAv/

However I have read the [css3 declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content) and I know that `content` should not work for `:hover`, which isn't a big deal since implementation is easy with javascript.

But, I then looked at it further and tried using the `a:hover::before` psuedo-class and that's where it gets really strange

Html:

```
<li id="menuDebating"><a href="xc_debating.htm">Debating</a></li>
```

Css:

```
#menuDebating a:hover::before{
content: "Public Speaking" !important;
color:red;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FSyAv/1/

In Chrome, it flickers non-stop, Safari flickers, then stops for while and continues flickering, while Mozilla and Opera runs the event as intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content` [can only be used with pseudo elements](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp) (`before` and `after`).

You can force it to "overwrite" the original word by setting its position to absolute:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/fBr2u/)

```
ul li {
    position:relative;
}
#menuDebating a:hover:before{
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
    content: "Public Speaking";
    color:red;
    background:#FFF;
}​
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like a hacky solution.. Nevertheless it works :)

Comment: Probably you better go for a JS solution anyway @extramaster , as it's not standard-compliant ;-)